# Is there any clever way to determine whether a point is in a rectangle?

Tags: algorithm

I want to calculate whether a point, `(x,y)`, is inside a rectangle which is determined by two points, `(a,b)` and `(c,d)`.

If `a<=c` and `b<=d`, then it is simple:

```
a<=x&&x<=c&&b<=y&&y<=d
```

However, since it is unknown whether `a<=c` or `b<=d`, the code should be

```
(a<=x&&x<=c||c<=x&&x<=a)&&(b<=y&&y<=d||d<=y&&y<=b)
```

This code may work, but it is too long. I can write a function and use it, but I wonder if there's shorter way (and should be executed very fast - the code is called a lot) to write it.

One I can imagine is:

```
((c-x)*(x-a)>=0)&&((d-y)*(y-b)>=0)
```

Is there more clever way to do this?

(And, is there any good way to iterate from a from c?)

Comment: That's not clever, so not an answer. Swap `a/c` and `b/d` as needed to ensure correct order, then apply the simple formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap the variables as needed so that a = x<sub>min</sub> and b = y<sub>min</sub>:

```
if a > c: swap(a,c)
if b > d: swap(b,d)

a <= x <= c and b <= y <= d
```

Shorter but slightly less efficient:

```
min(a,c) <= x <= max(a,c) and min(b,d) <= y <= max(b,d)
```

As always when optimizing you should profile the different options and compare hard numbers. Pipelining, instruction reordering, branch prediction, and other modern day compiler/processor  optimization techniques make it non-obvious whether programmer-level micro-optimizations are worthwhile. For instance it used to be significantly more expensive to do a multiply than a branch, but this is no longer always the case.

Answer (score 3):

I like the this:

```
((c-x)*(x-a)>=0)&&((d-y)*(y-b)>=0)
```

but with more whitespace and more symmetry:

```
(c-x)*(a-x) <= 0 && (d-y)*(b-y) <= 0
```

It's mathematically elegant, and probably the fastest too.  You will need to measure to really determine which is the fastest.  With modern pipelined processors, I would expect that straight-line code with the minimum number of operators will run fastest.

Comment: What you say might be true, but I think simple comparison(s) will be faster than doing 2 to 4 subtractions and 1 to 2 multiplications. What do you think?

Comment: @Sam: simple comparisons won't be faster than addition, and may not be faster than multiplication.  Branching is relatively slow.On a modern multiple ALU CPU, the four subtractions may occur in parallel, and the same for the two multiplications.

Answer (score 1):

While sorting the `(a, b)` and `(c, d)` pairs as suggested in the accepted answer is probably the best solution in this case, an even better application of this method would probably be to elevate the `a < b` and `c < d` requirement to the level of the program-wide invariant. I.e. require that all rectangles in your program are created and maintained in this "normalized" form from the very beginning. Thus, inside your point-in-rectangle test function you should simply assert that `a < b` and `c < d` instead of wasting CPU resources on actually sorting them in every call.

Answer (score 0):

Define intermediary variables `i = min(a,b)`, `j = min(c,d)`, `k = max(a,b)`, `l = max(c,d)`
Then you only need `i<=x && x<=k && j<=y && y<=l`.

EDIT: Mind you, efficiency-wise it's probably better to use your "too long" code in a function.